# Read values from excel and replace them in another file using Powershell

Tags: excel, scripting, powershell, replace

I need to find a way so that I can read values from an excel file and then replace all the corresponding values in another file accordingly. Basically, I found some discrepancy in one of the automated task we run and I need to convert some values within the file before I send it to the automated task. I have an excel file that list the "wrong" values and their corresponding "correct" values and I need to how Power shell can help me in this.

```
$docID = $args[0] $docid #Read Z ticker file
$Zfile = 'I:\IS\Rishabh\Z tickers Active.xls' # Find the .rps file imported automatically from schwab trust
$RPSFile= 'L:\Trading\Schwab Trust\Import\CS<%dmmdd-01yy>.RPS'
While (Get-Content $ZFile)
{
    $_-cmatch 'A$','B$'| Set-Variable X-ticker # End Loop
}
(Get-Content $RPSfile) | ForEach-Object { $_-replace '%, ' ,'X-ticker' #End Loop }
Set-Content $RPSFile
```

Comment: What language is the automated task running under?  It might be faster to read in the excel file using that program rather than involve an intermediary.

Comment: Rishabh, it sounds like you need a very large amount of code here. Might it not be easier to do with VBA?

Comment: Well the automated task is run through one our client application called Relius (so I don't know the language). What happens basically is, every morning we import a file (.rps format) from one of our trading partners that runs into Relius and gives us the results. But lately, that imported file contains some data which is not readable through Relius and the end result is bizarre. The imported file in not in excel but in .rps format. I need a way to read the excel file (that my co-worker sent me) and replace the "wrong" values accordingly in the .rps file before it runs into Relius

Comment: Have you looked at some of the sample code online for how to automate Excel using Powershell?

Comment: Okay, here's my code so far..                                                          $docID = $args[0]
$docid
#Read Z ticker file
$Zfile = 'I:\IS\Rishabh\Z tickers Active.xls'
# Find the .rps file imported automatically from schwab trust
$RPSFile= 'L:\Trading\Schwab Trust\Import\CS<%dmmdd-01yy>.RPS'
While (Get-Content $ZFile)
{
$_-cmatch 'A$','B$'| Set-Variable X-ticker
# End Loop
}
(Get-Content $RPSfile)| ForEach-Object{
$_-replace '%,     ' ,'X-ticker'
#End Loop
}
Set-Content $RPSFile

Comment: @Rishabh, I'm guessing: Google: "Excel automate Powershell" would be an excellent start.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Powershell. Excel itself has built in mechanisms for doing what you want. For example you could use the [LOOKUP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324986) function in Excel.

Comment: Well the automated task is run through one our client application called Relius (so I don't know the language). What happens basically is, every morning we import a file (.rps format) from one of our trading partners that runs into Relius and gives us the results. But lately, that imported file contains some data which is not readable through Relius and the end result is bizarre. The imported file in not in excel but in .rps format. I need a way to read the excel file (that my co-worker sent me) and replace the "wrong" values accordingly in the .rps file before it runs into Relius.

Comment: Okay, here's my code so far..                                                          $docID = $args[0]
$docid
#Read Z ticker file
$Zfile = 'I:\IS\Rishabh\Z tickers Active.xls'
# Find the .rps file imported automatically from schwab trust
$RPSFile= 'L:\Trading\Schwab Trust\Import\CS<%dmmdd-01yy>.RPS'
While (Get-Content $ZFile)
{
$_-cmatch 'A$','B$'| Set-Variable X-ticker
# End Loop
}
(Get-Content $RPSfile)| ForEach-Object{
$_-replace '%,     ' ,'X-ticker'
#End Loop
}
Set-Content $RPSFile

Comment: update your question with the code sample not the comments. Comments don't format the code well and no one is going to read it like that.